# How to change from .mdf file to SQL Server 2008 Management Studio without altering a typed dataset?

Tags: sql-server

I have an application developed in C# connecting to a SQL Server `.mdf` file through a typed dataset. The application can only be used by a single user since it’s a `.mdf` file. However, I want user it  in a network. I also want to change my database (which has tables, views and stored procedures) from `.mdf` to either SQL Server 2008 Management Studio or to MySQL 5.0.

What can I do to change the connection string to the new database in my typed dataset without altering the dataset?

Thanks in advance.

Gaitho

Comment: `.mdf` ***IS*** SQL server .....

Comment: @marc_s - couldn't it be an old MS Access database?

Comment: @SchmitzIT: MS-Access uses a `.mdb` extension - not `.mdf`

Comment: D'oh, you're right. I for some reason misread it as stating .mdb. I think it's finally time for that eye lasering.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to just simply **attach** your existing `.mdf` file (which already **IS** a SQL Server database file) to a SQL Server instance of the same (2008) or newer version, and then change your connection string to point to that new server instance.

The typed dataset shouldn't be affected by that.

Migrating to MySQL 5.0 however would not be that easy - you'd have to recreate everything in MySQL, migrate the data and I quite honestly don't know whether you'd be able to get away without touching the typed dataset ....

Answer (score 0):

```
USE [master]
GO
CREATE DATABASE [database_name] ON 
  ( FILENAME = N'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL11.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\Data\<database name>.mdf' ),
  ( FILENAME = N'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL11.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\Data\<database name>.ldf' )
FOR ATTACH ;
GO
```